# Grab specific value from Array of Objects based on value of object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects like this:

```
$scope.SACCodes = [
    {'code':'023', 'description':'Spread FTGs', 'group':'footings'},
    {'code':'024', 'description':'Mat FTGs', 'group':'footings'}
]
```

I want to write a function to grab the description based on the code, something like this:

```
$scope.SACDescription = function(code) {
     return $scope.SACCodes WHERE code=:code
}
```

I'm not sure of the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

Like this

```
$scope.SACDescription = function(code) {
     return $scope.SACCodes.filter(function(x){ return x.code == code; });
}
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/dnnqpva8/2/)**</kbd>